# How to delete words based on characters count in TextWrangler

Tags: textwrangler

I'm  deleting words that contains more than X characters using TextWrangler and i wonder if there's a way to select them with some kind of filter or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've found this solution in the documentation:
 `\w{x}` where x is the number of characters you are looking for.